# How to run the same script multiple times without waiting for it to finish

Tags: pycharm

In a previous version of PyCharm (don't remember which one) I was able to press run and a new tab would be created every time. I was able to run the program with different inputs at the same time. In this version (2019.2) I am not able to do this and a message says "[it] is not allowed to run in parallel.".

Is there an option or setting I need to change to be able to do this again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open `Run - Edit Configurations`, select corresponding run configuration and enable `Allow parallel run`

Answer (score 0):

Add in `–parallel=4` in the configuration interface, or however many instances you want to be able to be running, instead of 4

Comment: I don't know which configuration interface you are referring to. I'm assuming it's the `Run/Debug configurations`. I tried adding `-parallel=4` as a parameter in there and nothing changed.

Comment: https://andreasbergstrom.com/posts/python-django-pycharm-parallel-tests/